# Отправка файлов на сервер ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, файлы, asp.net, потоки-данных

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при отправке файла на сервер, он просто не сохраняется. Что я делаю не так, вот пример кода:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile files)
        {
            if (files == null || files.Length == 0)
                return BadRequest("file not selected");


            string rootPath = _env.WebRootPath+@"\images\"+files.FileName;
            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(rootPath))
            {
                await files.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            return Ok(files.FileName + " uploaded successfully " + "file location is " + rootPath);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    file.FormFile.CopyTo(stream);
}
```